# how to write Mongod Db Date query in JAVA

Tags: mongodb

: have written the query to search between two date ranges the usage of current.To filter the item i have written the following condition

```
{$match:{"consumption":{"$gte":new Date(1504704600000),"$lte":new Date(1504794600000)}
```

In java ,I  mapped the above query as

```
  Document doc=new Document();
              doc.put(QueryOperators.GTE,
                    new DateTime().toDate());
              doc.put(QueryOperators.LTE,
                    new DateTime().toDate());
```

The result of the above statement is

```
{ "$gte" : { "$date" : 1505543461301 }, "$lte" : { "$date" : 1505543461323 } }
```

So the problem is in java driver or something else as date field is not gets converted into right format. There is no official doc to explain such problems.

Comment: The representation is different, but the java translation is actually valid mongo. Have you tried running it ? I bet you will get the proper results.

Comment: Thanks Derlin.Your are right .I was looking the representation